# Adding menu item to every ContextMenu in the app

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I'm working an administrative application where certain actions need to be added every single context menu in the application.

I can always define the common context menu items in every single xaml wherever a ContextMenu is defined but there has to be a better way to achieve this without the repetition.

Comment: 1. You might be able to write a subclass of ContextMenu which automatically adds certain statically defined menu items, and then adds whatever items are defined for it in the XAML as well. 2. Populate all of your ContextMenus by binding their ItemsSource to a collection of commands on the viewmodel. All viewmodels could derive from a common base which defines the ContextMenuItem collection and adds the default items to it. Subclasses would add more items in their constructor, or in a virtual they can override if they want.

Comment: For #2 I think you'd want a collection not of commands, but of a `ContextCommand` class that has a command property, a Header, and an `ObservableCollection<ContextCommand> Children;` as well. You could write a HierarchicalDataTemplate for ContextMenuItem that would create submenus appropriately.